# Postgis, Installing Tiger Geocoder :Using Extension

Tags: installation, geocoding, postgis-2.2

I am trying to install the tiger geocoder for postGIS. I am using the 2.2 version of postGIS on Windows 10. I am using this set of instruction to do so.

I do not know the meaning of the fourth step.

I am confused by what they mean be edit the paths in the declare_sect column to those that fit your pg, unzip,shp2pgsql, psql, etc path locations.

Here's the code that I am using to do this.

```
INSERT INTO tiger.loader_platform(os, declare_sect, pgbin, wget, unzip_command, psql, path_sep, 
           loader, environ_set_command, county_process_command)
SELECT 'debbie', declare_sect, pgbin, wget, unzip_command, psql, path_sep, 
       loader, environ_set_command, county_process_command
  FROM tiger.loader_platform
  WHERE os = 'sh';
```

Can anybody tell me what to do. Please write down the specific steps.